# Does this type of recursion have a name?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a linked list in python and I want to write a filter function that returns a new link list if a call to `f(item)` is true, this implementation has a filtered that builds the list from the bottom up. I'm having trouble understanding this recursion. What type of recursion is this?

I'm more familiar with recursion like fibonacci where the return recursion is at the very bottom.

```
class Link:   
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i == 0:
            return self.first
        else:
            return self.rest[i-1]

    def __len__(self):
        return 1 + len(self.rest)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest == Link.empty:
            return "Link(" + str(self.first) + ")"

        return 'Link({0}, {1})'.format(self.first, repr(self.rest))


def filter_link(f, s):
    if s is Link.empty:
        return s
    else:
        filtered = filter_link(f,s.rest)   # How does this work?  
        if f(s.first):
            return Link(s.first, filtered)
        else:
            return filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

This *is* the sort of recursion you are used to.

I just looked up a recursive [fibonacci](http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2015/03/c-program-fibonacci-series-using-recursion.html) solution where the early return is on the second line, just like your code. Also, like your code, the recursion in the example occurs before the more normal returns.

It looks like your code returns a new linked list of the elements that the function `f` approves of, from the bottom up. That is, it creates new instances of `Link` around elements `s.first`, terminated by the single instance of `Link.empty`.